# How do I download mods on Garry's Mod for Mac?

Tags: mods, macos, garrys-mod

I have Garry's Mod for Macintosh. I can download maps with ease, but I'm unsure how to download general mods and SWEPs.

Comment: The mods are written in Lua, so it shouldn't be an issue - have you actually tried it?  Also, aren't mods downloaded automatically when you join a server in Garry's Mod?

Answer (score 1):

[Here you have disscusion](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1441922) on Steam Support about it.

> Go to ~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/[your
> username]/garrysmod/garrysmod/addons
>
> Place the folder containing the info.txt file in that addons folder.
>
> ( ~ means your user directory, your "home" directory)

Hope it helps.